# Proving convergence of improper integral: $\int_1^\infty \frac {\ln x} {1+x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove that this integral converges:
$$\int_1^\infty \frac {\ln x} {1+x^2}dx$$

I have tried so many different approaches, including all the tests I know of.
I can safely say I'm lost, and I would love some guidance, or a hint, if you think of anything.

Answer (score 9):

One has
$$
0\le\int_1^\infty \frac {\ln x} {1+x^2}dx\le\int_1^\infty \frac {\ln x} {x^2}\:dx=\left[-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln x}{x}\right]_1^\infty=1.
$$

Comment: So simple, should have thought of that.

Comment: This is both the tightest inequality (excluding equality, i.e. showing the integral converges to Catalans Constant) as well as being one of the simplest to show. Bravo.

Answer (score 7):

Through the substitution $x=\frac{1}{z}$ we have
$$ I =\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log z}{1+z^2}\,dz \tag{1}$$
but since $\int_{0}^{1}(-\log z)z^n\,dz = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, by expanding $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ as a Taylor series centered at $z=0$ and applying termwise integration to the RHS of $(1)$ we get:
$$ I = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)^2} \tag{2}$$
that is a clearly convergent series, equal to [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) $G$.

Another chance is given by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x^2}\,dx\leq\sqrt{\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log^2(x)}{x^2}\,dx\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx}\tag{3}$$
where the RHS of $(3)$ equals $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi+2}$.

Comment: Taylor series, I actually didn't think of this approach. Thanks.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain your downvote.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that for sufficiently large $x$, we have $\ln(x) < \sqrt{x}$.  Thus, for sufficiently large $x$, we have
$$
\frac{\ln(x)}{1 + x^2} \leq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1 + x^2} \leq 
\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2} = x^{-3/2}
$$

Comment: Oh man, I didn't know that. Thank you so much. This sounds sarcastic, that's not, lol.

Comment: No problem.  It helps to consider the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: Isn't ln(x) < square root of x, for x>0?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the limit
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}}=\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{x^{3/2}}{1+x^2}=\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{x^{2}\ln x}{1+x^2}\cdot\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}}=0.$$
Hence there is some $x_0>0$  such that for any $x\geq x_0$,
$$0\leq \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\leq \frac{1}{2x^{3/2}}\implies
0\leq \int_1^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\ dx\leq \int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}} <+\infty$$
because $3/2>1$.

Comment: Got it, thank you sir!